# FullCalendar V4 How to set attribute of calendar event after drop

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, drop

I'm using FullCalendar V4 callback function `drop`. I try to pass myID which are generated by server to be Calendar event.id, but I do not know how to do. The following is simple code

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {   
    drop: function( dropInfo  ) {
        $.getJSON( url, myParams, function( data ) {
            // try to set data.myID to FullCalendar event id
            calendarEvent = { id : data.myID  };
        });
    },
    eventClick: function( eventClickInfo ) {
        var msg = "Are you sure to delete[" + event.title + "]?";
        if ( confirm(msg) ) {
            // It fails, because I can't get event.id
            var params = { method: "deleteEvent", id: event.id };
            $.get(url, params, function( data ){
                eventClickInfo.event.remove();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried to put`calendar.refetchEvents();` into the `drop: $.getJSON(function(){})` response block, but FullCalendar makes 2 event in UI. One has balnk attribute, the other has right attribute. If I can  eliminate the redundancy, it will be a good solution.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what's going on overall due to the minimal code, but I think I know what you mean. If you want to get the details of the event which was dragged into the calendar, you can use the eventReceive callback instead of drop. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive

Comment: Thanks for ADyson comment. I have re-edit my question. I hope that the new post is clear.

Comment: ok so now I can see a simple problem which has nothing to do with the "drop" code at all.  In your eventClick, `event` is undefined. You forgot to put `eventClickInfo` in front of it, even though you've remembered later in the code...notice how you wrote `eventClickInfo.event.remove();`, because the event object is a property of the info object? Well you have to do that every time you refer to it, of course. So `eventClickInfo.event.title` and `eventClickInfo.event.id`. This would be a problem for any event, not just ones you dragged and dropped.

Comment: HI ADyson! I modify my post as your suggestion. I try to explain my question: object dropInfo (in callback function "drop") is refer to Drop Zone event, object eventClickInfo (in callback function "eventClick") is refer to FullCalendar Zone event. I want to deliver Drop Zone event ID that is made by AJAX to FullCalendar Zone event.

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, use the eventReceive callback instead of drop. There you can get access to the calendar event which was created by the drop option. And then you can update that event in the calendar and set it's ID. Then later when you click on it, the event will have the correct ID

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for ADyson's suggestion. Finally, I used callback function `eventReceive` solving the problem. The following is my simple code

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {   
    eventReceive: function( info ) {
        var $draggedEl = $( info.draggedEl );
        var params = { method: "insert" };
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, async: false});
        $.getJSON( myURL, params, function( data ){ // insert information into DB
            info.event.setProp( "id", data.id );
        });
    },
    eventClick: function( info ) {
        var event = info.event;
        var msg = "Are you sure to delete[" + event.title + "]?";
        if ( confirm(msg) ) {
            var params = { method: "deleteEvent", id: event._def.id };
            $.get( myURL, params, function( data ){
                event.remove();
            });
        }
    },
});
```